# Is my code secured?

Tags: php, authentication

I am using following code to login and creating session in my server. Is there anyway hackers can break this?? Here jp_objects is class.

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $check_login = new jp_objects('id','users',"username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'",'','');
    if ($check_login->nbResults != '0') {
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $check_login->results[0]->id;
        header("Location: home.php");
    } else {
        $message = '<span class="label label-danger">Please enter your correct password.</span>';
    }   
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Of course. You're not sanitizing it at all. My username is `; DROP TABLE users --`

Comment: I don't know what `jp_objects` does exactly, but there's no way this is SQL injection safe!

Answer (score 2):

No, your code have SQL Injection vulnerability. You don't filter $_POST['username'] enough.

Try to put `admin';--` (or another real username) to your login form and I think, you have been logged in without password.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--' AND password = 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

It's always in your best interest to use data error checking and validation.

Ex. `$username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $check_login = new jp_objects('id','users',"username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'",'','');`

Should do some error checking or validation such as

```
$username = $_POST['username'];

if((strlen($username)>20)||!(is_string($username)){
header("Location: LOCATION TO REDIRECT");
}

$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$check_login = new jp_objects('id','users',"username = '".$username."' AND password =       '".$password."'",'','');
```

Nothing is "hacker proof", but checking for data inconsistencies is good practice.  The above is just an example that ensures the string isn't longer than 20 characters and that it is a string.

Comment: Your code don't work to: `admin'--1234556789012345` and we logged in. You don't filter $username.

Comment: It's simply an example, I mean obviously there would be need for further error checking and validation; I was making a simple suggestion that could be expanded upon.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to vulnerability to SQL injections, you're also not salting your password and many people argue that MD5 shouldn't be used for cryptographic purposes any more either.

Here is the documentation on hashing a password with a salt: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 0):

No, it is very insecure.

1. You are not sanitizing your input. Any data that comes from the outside (i.e. from users or even services) should always be cleaned up and made safe. This can be done using the [`filter`](http://php.net/filter) extension (the [`filter_input()`](http://php.net/filter_input) function to be more specific).

   ```
   $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW);
   ```
2. You should use prepared statements, which add a layer of security. They prevent your queries from being vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection). Your database implementation is hidden behind a class so you will have to figure this out for yourself.
3. Hashing passwords using [`md5()`](http://php.net/md5) is not secure. It takes at most a few seconds to break most MD5 hashed passwords using a freely available password cracking program. You should use the [`password extension`](http://php.net/password) to hash your passwords. If you use PHP < 5.0.0 then you can us the [compatibility library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) maintained by Mr. [Anthony Ferrara](https://github.com/ircmaxell).

   ```
   $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
   ```
4. The code that you have shown us looks like a snippet from a bigger script. If this is so then you should also terminate the script after redirecting the user. After setting the `Location` header use `exit;` to stop the script from continue running. Using absolute paths (giving the full path to the page, using a `/` prefix) is also a good idea when redirecting.

   ```
   header("Location: /home.php");
   exit;
   ```